# Unable to kill a process

Tags: powershell, process, powershell-4.0

With admin rights and Powershell, I want to kill a nasty process.

`PS D:\_prj> Get-Process someapp* | Stop-Process -Force` (or without `-Force`).

That works in 99% of cases. Unfortunately, sometimes it don't. After executing the command I check whether the process is killed and get:

```
PS D:\_prj> Get-Process someapp*

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
    425      46    47052      60364   189     0,88  17316   2 someappHandler
```

Why? What's the PS solution to such problem? It may be worth noting that killing it via Task Manager works just fine.

Comment: Why aren't you using cmd and with taskkill?

Comment: Because I marked this question as a Powershell problem. Just like _C_ questions don't expect _Python_ answers.

Comment: Does "with admin rights" mean that your PowerShell session is properly elevated (window title = "Administrator: Windows PowerShell")?

Comment: Yes, "Administrator: Windows Powershell" is the exact title of the PS window.

Comment: I've had the same issue.  Usually this meant another process or service was using the process I was attempting to kill. The best way to get around this is to run the Stop-Process Silently and then doing a process status check.